# What is wrong with my smb.conf? I can browse files but not read them

Tags: samba, file-sharing, nas

I have an old Asus router with USB3 port that I have set up Samba, and it only support SMB1 (NT1)

Here is my smb.conf:

```
[global]
server string = File Server
workgroup = PERSONAL
client lanman auth = yes
client NTLMv2 auth = no
client use spnego = no
client min protocol = CORE
client max protocol = SMB3
security = user
map to guest = Bad User
name resolve order = bcast host
include = /etc/samba/shares.conf
server min protocol = NT1
ntlm auth = ntlmv1-permitted
```

I came up with this because I followed multiple tutorials and am getting confused what each of the setting is doing. I'm at the point where I can browse the files to see the list of my media files, but when I try to open the file, I just get error loading. I can't copy the files as well. I have my user permission set correctly.

Can anyone suggest how to clean up my smb.conf to get it working? Thanks!

I'm on Ubuntu Studio 22.02, Samba version 4.15.9

Comment: "Can anyone suggest how to clean up my smb.conf to get it working? Thanks!" restore it to your systems default? `/etc/samba/shares.conf`  might also be the problem ;)

Comment: I tried restore to system default, still can't read the files.
The shares.conf is working fine, it's for my Samba server. Basically I have a Window PC would read the shared folder in my Ubuntu machine, that's what the shares.conf is for and it's working fine.

The problem is the samba client, it just refuse to read files from my shared disk in the Asus router, and I just found out it won't read files from my TruNAS box either.

Comment: Could you also post the content of `shares.conf`?

Comment: Sorry I was out of country for a 3 weeks. Here is the content of shares.conf:

[PC Transfer]
#path = /share/pc_transfer
path = /media/Ubuntu_share
force user = smbuser
force group = smbgroup
create mask = 0664
force create mode = 0664
directory mask = 0775
force directory mode = 0775
public = yes
writable = yes